# The .wvx file not playing in a silver light player

Tags: silverlight

The video file with the .wvx extension is not playing when i embed it in a silverlight player, whereas the file plays when i open it directly in a browser. And all the other files like (.mp4,wav are playing). Please tell me if anyone knows how to play .wvx video through a silverlight player

here is my code

```
<object width="640" height="480" id="PlayerControl" data="data:application/x-silverlight-2,"
    type="application/x-silverlight-2">
    <param name="source" value="ClientBin/MediaPlayerTemplate.xap"  />
    <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true"/>
    <param name="initParams" value="mediaurl= http://localhost:4627/joe-lg.wvx"  />
    <param name="minruntimeversion" value="2.0.31005.0"/>
    <div style="width: 640px; height: 480px; margin-top: 200px; ">
    <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=124807" style="text-decoration: none;">
    </a>
    </div>
```